# Java Menu Loop Repeats Infinitely

Tags: java, loops, menu

So here is my main class for the program.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;
public class seu03
{
public static void main (String[] args)
{
int option = 0;
option = seu03Methods.seu03Menu();
    while(option != 9)
        {
switch (option)
    {
    case 1:
        seu02.calculator();
        break;
    case 2:
        seu03Methods.sentenceAnalysis();
        break;
    case 3:
        seu03Methods.rollDice();
        break;
    case 4:
        seu03Methods.bigMoney();
        break;
    case 9:
        System.out.println("Exiting seu03...");
        System.exit(0);
        break;
    default:
        System.out.println("Invalid selection.");
        break;
    }
            }
} //end of main
} //end of class
```

And this is the "methods" class.

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
    import java.util.Random;
    public class seu03Methods
{
    public static int seu03Menu()
    {
    int option = 0;
    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);   
    System.out.println("-------------------------------------");
    System.out.println("|         Welcome to seu03!         |");
    System.out.println("|-----------------------------------|");
    System.out.println("| Choose an option below:           |");
    System.out.println("|                                   |");
    System.out.println("| 1.  Calculator                    |");
    System.out.println("| 2.  Sentence Analysis             |");
    System.out.println("| 3.  Roll a 6-sided die            |");
    System.out.println("| 4.  Play Big Money!               |");
    //System.out.println("| 5. randomRange            |");
    //System.out.println("| 6. stubMethod            |");
    System.out.println("| 9.  Exit                          |");
    System.out.println("-------------------------------------");
    option = console.nextInt();
    return option;
    }
    public static void sentenceAnalysis()
    {
    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
    String userString = new String("");
    System.out.println("-------------------------------------");
    System.out.println("Please enter a sentence for analysis:");
    userString = console.nextLine();
    System.out.println("The sentence to analyze is: " + userString);
    System.out.println("The sentence is " + userString.length() + " characters long.");
    System.out.println("The first character of the sentence is " + userString.charAt(0));
    System.out.println("The middle charchter of the sentence is " + userString.charAt(userString.length()/2));
    System.out.println("The last character of the sentence is " + userString.charAt(userString.length()-1));
    System.out.println("Thanks for using our 1323 System!");
    System.out.println("-------------------------------------");
    return;
    } //end of sentenceAnalysis
    public static void rollDice()
    {
    Random gener = new Random();
    int die = 0;
    System.out.println("-------------------------------------");
    System.out.println("Welcome to Roll Dice!");
    System.out.println("The program will now roll a single six-sided die.");
    die = gener.nextInt(6) + 1;
    System.out.println("Result: " + die);
    System.out.println("Thanks for using our 1323 System!");
    System.out.println("-------------------------------------");
    return;
    } //end of rollDice
    public static void bigMoney()
    {
    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
    Random gener = new Random();
    int rnum = 0;
    int guess1 = 0;
    int guess2 = 0;
    int guess3 = 0;
    System.out.println("-------------------------------------");
    System.out.println("Welcome to Big Money!");
    rnum = gener.nextInt(10) + 1;
    System.out.println("A whole number between 1 and 10 inclusive has been generated. You will have three chances to guess the number.");
    System.out.println("Here is the random number for testing purposes: " + rnum);
    System.out.println("What is your first guess?");
    guess1 = console.nextInt();
    if(guess1 == rnum)
        {
        System.out.println(" Big Money! You win $100!");
        }
    else
        {
        System.out.println("No good! What is your second guess?");
        guess2 = console.nextInt();
            if(guess2 == rnum)
            {
            System.out.println("Medium Money! You win $50!");
            }
            else
                {
                System.out.println("No good! What is your third guess?");
                guess3 = console.nextInt();
                    if(guess3 == rnum)
                    {
                    System.out.println("Little Money! You win $1!");
                    }
                        else
                        {
                        System.out.println("Sorry! You didn't win any money this time. Better luck next time!");
                        }
                }
            }   
    System.out.println("Thanks for playing Big Money!");
    System.out.println("Thanks for using our 1323 System!");
    System.out.println("-------------------------------------");
    return;
    } //end of bigMoney
} //end of class
```

If I choose an option, say, 3, that option will repeat forever (until I close the command line). I missed class Tuesday (thanks for not going off alarm!) and thus missed our lecture on loops. :/ If anyone could provide some assistance (maybe some pointers?) that would be greatly appreciated! All I want is to choose an option, do what is in that method, then return to the menu to choose another method until the user selects "9" and exits. And I need to get rid of that horrid nested if later too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

move `option = seu03Methods.seu03Menu();` into the while loop( down two lines into `while(option != 9){..`.) You never change `option` in the loop it so it is always three

Comment: Ah. Of course it would be something so simple. *shakes head* Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
while(option != 9)
        {
switch (option)
    {
    case 1:
        seu02.calculator();
        break;
    case 2:
        seu03Methods.sentenceAnalysis();
        break;
    case 3:
        seu03Methods.rollDice();
        break;
    case 4:
        seu03Methods.bigMoney();
        break;
    case 9:
        System.out.println("Exiting seu03...");
        System.exit(0);
        break;
    default:
        System.out.println("Invalid selection.");
        break;
    }
            }
```

you can never get to your case : 9, to exit....because the while loop is telling it to skip the switch if the int is 9 ( which i assume would close the app) try changing this

```
while(option != 9)
```